# Qt creator: "cannot find -lGl" Cannot install libglu1-mesa-dev

Tags: apt, qt

I am trying to compile and run a QT program. I have already tried windows (couldn't get taglib to compile); I also tried OSX, I compiled but the program crashes even though it doesn't crash on my friend's ubuntu. So I decided to install ubuntu. Now I face the error: "`cannot find -lGl`". I googled, and people say to do `sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev`, but it keeps giving me dependency errors. I rather unfamiliar with ubuntu/linux. I'm using the latest ubuntu (14.04 LTS).

When I run `sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev`, I get:

```
Reading package lists...Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
 libglu1-mesa-dev : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dev or 
                             libgl-dev
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a 
solution).
```

Then I run `sudo apt-get -f install` :

```
Reading package lists...Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies ... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libglu1-mesa-dev : Depends: libglu1-mesa (= 8.0.4-0ubuntu0.7) but 9.0.0-2 is installed
                    Depends: libgl1-mesa-dev or
                             libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-quantal but it is not installed or
                             libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-raring but it is not installed or
                             libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-saucy but it is not installed or
                             libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-trusty but it is not installed or
                             libgl-dev
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

I tried sudo apt-get install libgl-dev, or any thing else (really), but they all gave me dependency errors.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install `libgl1-mesa-dev` to get the `libgl.so` file which Qt links against to.